# compare a model property using if null or empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this condition for validation of email property that if its null or empty throw this message.

```
if (this.CCommmunication == Commmunication.Email && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Email))
{
yield return new ValidationResult("Please enter email address", new[] { "Email" }); //returns message
}
```

Now I want to compare the above property with confirm email address property so it matches above. The property I want to use for comparing is  `public string ConfirmEmailAddress { get; set; }`.

I want to do something something similar to above if.

Comment: Since you validate that email is required appropriately, you could confirm that ConfirmEmailAddress matches Email.  So when it's not required, both will be blank, or when required, both will have a value that should be the same.

Comment: Whats the code way to show this  @BrianMains

Comment: `if (this.Email != this.ConfirmEmailAddress) { return new ValidationResult(..); }`  If one entry is NULL, then it won't match the null check - otherwise, this does a straight string compare.  To allow case insensitivity, string.Compare is a better option for that.